# jQuery hover() hide/show causing bounce

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's a simple hide/show menu: 
When you mouseover a list item, the script shows any unordered lists that are children of that list item, and then displays. The CSS puts this sub-list to the immediate right of the list item hovered.
When you mouseout, it hides that unordered list again.

The HTML:

```html
<div class="menu-header-category-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-header-category-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-58"><a href="?cat=3">Parent Category I</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-59"><a href="?cat=6">Child Category I</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-60">
          <a href="?cat=7">Child Category II</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-61"><a href="?cat=9">Grandchild Category I</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-62"><a href="?cat=4">Parent Category II</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-63">
      <a href="?cat=5">Parent Category III</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-64"><a href="?cat=8">Child Category III</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-57"><a href="?cat=1">Uncategorized</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
li {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: aqua;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(
        function() { $(this).children('ul').show('slow'); },
        function() { $(this).children('ul').hide('slow'); }
    );
});
```

It works mostly like it should. Except if you move the mouse from over the list item and leave it in the space where the sub-list should appear (before the sublist finishes showing) you get it stuck in a show/hide/show/hide repeating loop until you move the mouse cursor away.

I've tried to fix this using setTimeout() in both the mouseover argument's function and in the mouseout argument's function. I've also tried using conditions to check if the sublist is hidden in those arguments. I'm not seeing any performance difference.

Anyone

Comment: Try binding the mouseover handler to the anchor instead of the list item. I have a feeling it'll clear right up.

Comment: I can see the logic in that (since the li contains the submenu) but, won't that cause the submenu to disappear when you mouse off of the anchor (which you would do if you needed to click something in the submenu)

Comment: Derp. Looked before I leapt, so that is not indeed the solution, but I have a feeling that's the source of the issue somehow. It seems the mouseover on a list item should hide any visible sub-menus on the current level then show its own, with a mouseout on the top-level ul to hide any visible sub-menus.

Comment: Have you tried adding the stop() function before your show and hide calls? It might simplify the event handling in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, check out [Hover Intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: it's interesting. I used Hover Intent, and it's harder to accidentally trigger the bug, but if I intend to do so, I can get it to happen. I wonder if that's something I'm just going to have to live with.

Comment: i worked a little more, and using the timeout argument made it almost impossible to duplicate. I'm pretty sure that I won't be bothered by this again. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think it catches your mouseout event before showing submenu. Try changing show/hide speed to fast. But this is not a solution.

Comment: yeah, the unfortunate thing about that is the appearance issue.

Answer (score 0):

**This code will also avoid multiple bouncing**

```
 var myVar;
 $(".liveUser").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
        myVar = setTimeout(function(){ //optional delay
             //$(".userDetail").stop().hide().fadeIn();
               $(".userDetail").stop().hide().show();
                 }, 400);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            clearTimeout(myVar);
            //$(".userDetail").stop().fadeOut();
            $(".userDetail").stop().hide();
       }
   });
```